# on click drag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way i can detect when someone clicks and drags?

Im asking because its not registering as .click  when i click drag and drop. (I am **not** using jquery UI). It only registers if i click on it and dont move the element

What can I do to solve this problem that I am having?

My code:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".word", function() {
            $('#dragHelpTxt').hide();
        });
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking **dragstart** or **dragstop** event. If so then you can add both listeners at once:

```
$(document).on("click dragstart", ".word", function(e)
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq5vegL0/).